# Intercept a link and redirect with router from component

Tags: javascript, angular

Because I can't bind angular directives with [innerHTML], I have replaced all `routerlink` with normal `<a href=link>` link. Now I want when user click an a link to intercept it redirect with router from component.

Example:

```
Hello <a href=world>world</a>
```

When user click this I don't want to load a new page but redirect with router from component:

```
  This.router.navigate('world');
```

Is it possible ? If yes how to do it ?

Comment: Yes, just add an event listener to the click event and use event.preventDefault()  to prevent the browser from loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to somehow grab the DOM element<sup>1</sup> and attach an event listener to it, and then use regular DOM API to intercept the click.

The “most Angular” way to grab an element is to place a reference on it, with the `#` symbol:

```
<a href=world #ref>world</a>
```

Now, from the class, you can get your hands on the reference with the following decorated property.

```
@ViewChild('ref') refEl: ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>
```

After the view is created (so in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook), the property will be initialized with the reference, so you can access it and attach the event listener.

```
this.refEl.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // handler here
})
```

The handler can simply invoke the router, or whichever you want to do.

```
this.router.push('page')
```

Don't forget to `e.preventDefault()` or otherwise the browser would still do its job and send a request to the server for a new page.

---

<sup>1</sup> This becomes slightly more complex if your application needs to support some sort of universal rendering (like server-side rendering).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Click) function with parameter  and then writer navigating logic in click function if it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)